# Sending a date and timezone from GAE server to GWT client

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, timezone, gwt-rpc

OK folks, I have been going around this problem for about 2 weeks now trying everything I can think of and looking at tons of answers on here that feel like they are going to answer it, but I just cant work out how I am meant to do what I am trying to do and it is driving me absolutely NUTS! No one seems to have an answer anywhere, there are half answers all over the place, but none seem to actually do what I need it to do, surely SOMEONE has solved this problem before! Please excuse the REALLY long question, but its important that the question is asked right, so that the answers actually answer the need! :D

Also please don't bother reading any further if you are likely to provide any answer which does not take into account that my datastore/server is Google App Engine (GAE), and my Client is written in Google Web Toolkit (GWT) and everything is written in Java, I dont know anything about Python or MySQL or PHP or anything like that

Finally if anyone knows of a better place to figure stuff out like this, PLEASE do let me know as I keep coming up with issues like this and have no idea how to find a solution other than in here, or spend hours and hours searching google for someone else who has already managed to figure it out. I also dont understand how to figure anything out from JavaDocs - sorry, but until someone explains it to me, Im just not going to get it

I have a datetime stored on the server (in UTC obviously) I also have stored on the server a TimeZone for each business owner stored as a string (eg `"America/New_York"`). This string is obtained by using `java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` on the server and getting the business owner to select the relavant timezone for their business (default is `"Europe/London"` if they don't choose anything - no need to get hung up on that bit) I need to pass any datetimes back to the client PC at some point in the future, IGNORING the local timezone on their PC, because the datetime needs to be displayed according to the timezone of the business owner.

So as an example the business owner is a hairdressers in London and they have an online appointment schedule which is available to be viewed by any potential customer of theirs. One of these customers (also in London) wants to book an appointment, sees a slot at 9am BST on Monday 3rd September and books it.

This is then stored in the Datastore as the UTC time (which is actually 0800 as BST is UTC+1), and of course the business owner has selected `"Europe/London"` as their timezone. Everything fine so far.

NOW, at some point in the future, the customer is on a business meeting in New York, and realises that they have an appointment the following week for a haircut in London and they want to move it by a week, so they then try to VIEW the appointment (in the hairdressers appointment book), but they don't want to see it as 4am New York Time, they want to see it as 9am British time.

So my problem is that when the customer clicks to VIEW appointments on 3rd September, the server can send back a UTC datetime of 0800 and a `java.util.TimeZone` ID String of `"Europe/London"`

But because on the client I can only use

```
com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone
```

it doesn't allow me to use the function

```
TimeZone bizTimeZone=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London")
(which works for `java.util.TimeZone`)
```

as it causes the error

```
"The method getTimeZone(String) is undefined for the type TimeZone"
```

it suggests changing it to

```
com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone.createTimeZone("Europe/London")
```

but this version, is expecting a GWT `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZoneConstants` "object" (example shown at the end of this message) and not the simple string that the `java.util.TimeZone.createTimeZone()` will accept.

I can create this by using:

```
final TimeZoneConstants constTz = GWT.create(TimeZoneConstants.class);
final TimeZone timeZoneCali = TimeZone.createTimeZone(constTz.europeLondon());
```

But I dont know how to do this when Im starting with `"Europe/London"` and/or I dont know how to store this object into the App Engine DataBase and then retrieve it later.

Incidentally amongst the commented text I have also tried using the following lines:

```
//Calendar tmad = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
//Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(someTimeZone);
//DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
//df1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
//final TimeZone timeZoneClient = TimeZone.createTimeZone("Europe/London");
//dtf.format(date,timeZoneClient)
```

There MUST be a standard way of doing this SURELY, I really cant be the first person to ever have to solve this issue!

> constTz.europeLondon()={"transitions": [19394, 60, 24770, 0, 28130,
>   60, 33506, 0, 36866, 60, 42242, 0, 45602, 60, 50978, 0, 54506, 60,
>   59714, 0, 63242, 60, 68450, 0, 71978, 60, 77354, 0, 80714, 60, 86090,
>   0, 89450, 60, 94826, 0, 98521, 60, 103561, 0, 107257, 60, 112297, 0,
>   115993, 60, 121033, 0, 124729, 60, 129937, 0, 133633, 60, 138673, 0,
>   142369, 60, 147409, 0, 151105, 60, 156145, 0, 159841, 60, 164881, 0,
>   168577, 60, 173785, 0, 177313, 60, 182521, 0, 186217, 60, 191257, 0,
>   194953, 60, 199993, 0, 203689, 60, 208729, 0, 212425, 60, 217465, 0,
>   221161, 60, 226201, 0, 230065, 60, 235105, 0, 238801, 60, 243841, 0,
>   247537, 60, 252577, 0, 256273, 60, 261481, 0, 265009, 60, 270217, 0,
>   273745, 60, 278953, 0, 282649, 60, 287689, 0, 291385, 60, 296425, 0,
>   300121, 60, 305329, 0, 308857, 60, 314065, 0, 317593, 60, 322801, 0,
>   326329, 60, 331537, 0, 335233, 60, 340273, 0, 343969, 60, 349009, 0,
>   352705, 60, 357913, 0, 361441, 60, 366649, 0, 370177, 60, 375385, 0,
>   379081, 60, 384121, 0, 387817, 60, 392857, 0, 396553, 60, 401593, 0,
>   405289, 60, 410497, 0, 414025, 60, 419233, 0, 422761, 60, 427969, 0,
>   431665, 60, 436705, 0, 440401, 60, 445441, 0, 449137, 60, 454345, 0,
>   457873, 60, 463081, 0, 466609, 60, 471817, 0, 475513, 60, 480553, 0,
>   484249, 60, 489289, 0, 492985, 60, 498025, 0, 501721, 60, 506929, 0,
>   510457, 60, 515665, 0, 519193, 60, 524401, 0, 528097, 60, 533137, 0,
>   536833, 60, 541873, 0, 545569, 60, 550777, 0, 554305, 60, 559513, 0,
>   563041, 60, 568249, 0, 571777, 60, 576985, 0, 580681, 60, 585721, 0,
>   589417, 60, 594457, 0], "names": ["GMT", "Greenwich Mean Time", "BST",
>   "British Summer Time"], "id": "Europe/London", "std_offset": 0}

Comment: There is probably something i'm missing, but can't you just convert the date on the server side with java.util.TimeZone and send the converted date to the client?

Comment: I don't think you can do that can you? surely the timezone is only a formatting thing applied to the date itself, unless you are suggesting that I apply the timezone, format as a string then parse it and send back as a string array? EG `string[]={"2012","09","03","09","00","00"};`

Comment: yes, that is pretty much what I meant (sorry for not being clearer)

Comment: No problem I am currently testing that out as, at the very least, an interim solution! Still surprised that there is not a better solution though....

Comment: By looking at the doc, the other solution I see is using TimeZone and TimeZoneConstants from the com.google.gwt.i18n.client package. Maybe something like TimeZone.createTimeZone(timeZoneConstants.europeLondno())?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but I dont know how to establish that i should be using `timeZoneConstants.europeLondon()` rather than say `timeZoneConstants.americaLosAngeles()`

But your earlier suggestion ACTUALLY does work (or seems to so far anyway) more testing required of course!

Comment: Great. If it turns out to work, i'll write these comments as an answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue with v2.4.

I think Riley Lark is right.

*TimeZone.createTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo")* did not work in GWT 2.4

However, I found I could get the Tokyo zone by using the browser's default setting via:

```
Date d = new Date();
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.createTimeZone(d.getTimezoneOffset());
```

That is really what Riley Lark is suggesting for you since europeLondon has "std_offset": 0...

> TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.createTimeZone(0);

Comment: Offset changes depending on a date. You may get the wrong time zone as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, for example, `TimeZone.createTimeZone("Europe/London");`?  At least in newer versions of GWT, this method accepts a whole bunch of names, evidently prepared "from CLDR and Olson time zone database[sic]".  The documentation specifically references your use case: transferring timezone via json.

See [the properties file](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/constants/TimeZoneConstants.properties?r=3655) - it seems like it has all of the standard names for timezones.

If that doesn't do it for you, you could transmit the offset of the timezone in minutes, and then create your timezone with `TimeZone.createTimeZone(offsetInMinutes)`.

Comment: I have tried TimeZone.createTimeZone("Europe/London"); and it doesnt work on my current version GWT 2.2, but I note that v2.4 is available to upgrade to, so I could try that...

Comment: Yeah, I don't know in what version it became available.  Might be worth a try~

Comment: I have now upgraded to GWT 2.4 (latest version) and the line `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone.createTimeZone("Europe/London")` still crashes my GWT client and the documentation states:
`com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone.createTimeZone(String tzJSON)`
and
`This factory method creates a time zone instance from a JSON string that contains the time zone information for desired time zone. Applications can get such a string from the TimeZoneConstants class`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I needed to keep the server timezone on the client side. It was a bit challenging since GWT doesn't allow serialization of object  s from recent java libraries for example java.time.ZonedDateTime. Here is a hack I did to create a java.util.Date object with a timezone of your choice.

```
/*
    * This method forces a java.util.Date object to use a hard coded timezone.
    * The method first discards any local timezone from the Date object,
    * then adds a given timezone with the time. The purpose is to keep the 
    * original timestamp unchanged to avoid server-clinet timezone mismatch and use the 
    * server side timestamp. 
    */
    public java.util.Date updateZonedUtil(java.util.Date aDate)
    {
        // hard coding timezone with server timezone.
        String timezone = "America/Toronto";
        
        java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(aDate.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String strDate = formatter.format(utilDate);        
   
        DateTimeFormatter localFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime localdt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, localFormatter);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = localdt.atZone(ZoneId.of(timezone));
                
        return Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
    }
```