# How do I get the UTC offset for a timezone in Java?

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime, timezone-offset

Given a timezone (`America/New_York`), how do I go about getting the UTC offset?

I have tried using `java.util.TimeZone` but had no luck. I am fine with using Joda Time as well if the solution is viable in that.

Comment: TimeZone should work, please add the code you've tried to the question, and include any exceptions, output, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The offset for a particular time zone can vary based on the current time because of daylight savings, etc.  UTC doesn't have daylight savings, but "America/New_York" will change offsets with the daylight savings switch.  Therefore, the offset is a function of *both* the current time and the timezone.   The answers here give some examples of how to get the current offset:

[Java TimeZone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399491/java-timezone-offset)

Answer (score 3):

Note: Current offset depends on

- raw tz-offset
- day-savings time (DST) for a CURRENT moment.

This is well described in near answer.

Useful snippets:

- `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Kiev").getOffset(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());`
  will give you integer offset in millisecons
- `String.format("%tz", Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev")));`
  will give you a standardized string representation like "+0300"