# Java 8 ZoneOffset - How to get current system UTC offset

Tags: java, time, java-8, utc, java-time

I want to get current **ZoneOffset** of my system.
I tried to do that but I couldn't find a way.
Also, I was looking for a solution but I didn't find any.
Is it possible to do that in Java?

EDIT:
My question is different to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399491/java-timezone-offset). I would like to know the current system UTC, not how to convert between TimeZone offset representation or TimeZone storing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java TimeZone offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399491/java-timezone-offset)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
ZoneOffset.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(Instant.now())
```

or you can replace Instant instance with LocalDateTime instance:

```
ZoneOffset.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(LocalDateTime.now())
```

Comment: There is a key difference between these two options. The `Instant` version will always give the right answer. The `LocalDateTime` version will give the ["best available offset"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getOffset-java.time.LocalDateTime-). This is because of DST, where there may be two valid offsets for the `LocalDateTime`, or none.

Comment: I can confirm that, when both examples are ran, the following happens in Brazil: if ran outside of DST, `-03:00` is returned; if ran when in DST, `-02:00` is returned. Tested by changing the system's date.

Answer (score 35):

Your request has two parts:

- the offset of "my system" - thus you need the system time-zone - `ZoneId.systemDefault()`
- the "current" offset - thus you need the current instant - `Instant.now()`

These are tied together  using `ZoneRules`, to get the following:

```
ZoneOffset o = ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
```

---

For simplicty, you might want to use `OffsetDateTime`:

```
ZoneOffset o = OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset();
```

This works because `OffsetDateTime.now()` uses both `ZoneId.systemDefault()` and `Instant.now()` internally.

Comment: Confirmed just like my other comment.

Comment: Nice compact answer. Also, here's how to get from ZoneOffset to millis: OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset().get(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS) * 1000L;